# Why we don't need to import any modules to use print(),input(),len(),int(),etc function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

As definition say, To use any built-in  functions we need to first import the respective modules in the program
But how we are using print(), input(), len(), etc many more function without importing any modules in python

**Please someone clarify it..**
*(sorry if my question is not relevant)*

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Python language designers chose to make [them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) available by default, on the assumption that they were useful enough to always be available. This is especially common for:

1. The simplest I/O functions (e.g. `print`/`input`) that it's nice to have access to, especially when playing around with stuff in the interactive interpreter
2. Functions that are wrappers around special methods (e.g. `len` for `__len__`, `iter` for `__iter__`), as it reduces the risk of people calling special methods directly just to avoid an `import`
3. [Built-in classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) (e.g. `int`, `set`, `str`, etc.), which aren't technically functions, but they're used frequently (possibly available as literals), and the definition of the class needs to be loaded for basic operation of the interpreter anyway

In short, you have access to them automatically because they might have to load them anyway (in the case of built-in classes), it's convenient to have access to them automatically, and the designers thought it was likely they'd be frequently used, nothing more complicated than that. The "likely to be frequently used" is important; some modules on the CPython reference interpreter are actually baked into the interpreter itself, rather than existing as separate modules on the file system (e.g. `sys`), but the contents of those modules were not considered important/commonly used enough to be worth injecting into the built-in namespace (where they'd be likely to collide with user-defined names).

The built-ins are provided through [the `builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), so if you want to see what's there (or, being terrible, change what's available as a built-in *everywhere*), you can import it and perform normal attribute manipulation on it to query/add/remove/change the set of available built-ins ([the `site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) does this to inject [the `exit` quasi-built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) for instance).